# Problems with amount square

Tags: javascript, node.js, square

I have the following problem using nodejs sdk.

It turns out that a platform that processes payments of 200 usd and up.

Apparently the payments in the square system go wrong.

In my personal system they are well saved in the database with the amount entered.

The amount is sent and converted into a whole number.

Example of delivery: 1,250.00 and it becomes 1250 but in square it takes it as 12.50, I await your response, thank you

[Example transactions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1EIB.jpg)

Comment: Hi Edinson CS and welcom to SO. If you are new here please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and check out [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please add your code relevant to your question where you send your amount to square. Right now there is no way we can tell what should be done.

Answer (score 0):

You should multiply your amount by 100 since it's amount of cents. So instead of `1250` you should send `125000`.

[Square's API documentation](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/build-basics/working-with-monetary-amounts):

> All monetary fields in Square APIs are represented by a Money object with an amount field in the smallest denomination of the currency indicated by `currency_code`. For example, the following code represents 400 cents ($4.00 USD):
>
> ```json
> {
>   "amount": 400,
>   "currency_code": "USD"
> }
> ```